# "Model Item passed into dictionary" error, but passed in and required are the SAME model

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have read several different questions all asking about the ASP.NET error message "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '[Foo]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type '[Bar]'".  However, I'm getting a version of the error in which [Foo] and [Bar]  are the same model!

[image: passed in ViewModels.Templates.ShopFrontPageViewModel, and requires ViewModels.Templates.ShopFrontPageViewModel, so what's the issue?]

As you can see, the dictionary requires a model item of type `ViewModels.Templates.ShopFrontPageViewModel`, and indeed it was passed in a model item of type `ViewModels.Templates.ShopFrontPageViewModel`.  So what is the actual problem?  The error message does not tell me anything useful.

This error occurs maybe once a month or so, and each time, it's "solved" by resetting IIS's application pool, but surely that can't be something we're just supposed to accept and live with?  Can anyone point me to something I can even investigate to understand why MVC is complaining that it got exactly what it required?

Comment: By any chance are you modifying the site while it is live?  For example, deploying a new version of one DLL, or editing a cshtml  file.

Comment: @JohnWu we do have synchs scheduled every day to update the site, but the problem arises at times unrelated to when the synchs are running.

Comment: My guess is that a portion of your project is compiled just-in-time, but one of the target DLLs is locked at the moment it is supposed to be overwritten, possibly by something like an anti-virus scanner. As a result you have a dependency on a different *version* of an assembly than the one that is in place. That is just a guess. This isn't going to be easy to solve, and is probably not due to a code flaw.